# Rmarkdown text highlighting not showing up in PDF output

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I attempt to highlight text in Rmarkdown using single backticks, my html output will include both highlighting and monospacing, but the PDF output only produces text with monospace but no highlighting. Syntax highlighting works fine in both outputs.

Here is an example:

```r
---
title: "Highlighting"
output: 
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

Syntax highlighting works fine, but when I highlight `text like this`, it highlights in the html output but not the pdf.
```

I have explored pandoc and rmarkdown documentation but am not able to find any guidance on this specific problem.  Any ideas for troubleshooting are appreciated.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bookdownplus_1.5.7 bookdown_0.13      tinytex_0.15      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2      digest_0.6.20   crayon_1.3.4    magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.14   xaringan_0.11   pillar_1.4.2    rlang_0.4.0     magick_2.0      rmarkdown_1.15  tools_3.6.0    
[12] xfun_0.7        yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.6.0  pkgconfig_2.0.2 htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.24      tibble_2.1.3
```

Comment: Hi, you could use the following LaTeX code : ``\hl{TextYouWantHighlighted}``. This will work for the ``.pdf`` output. Simply add those packages ``soul`` and ``color``.

Comment: After installing those packages, I get an "! Undefined control sequence." error -- is there something else I need to add to the yaml to avoid this?

Comment: Those are LaTeX packages not R packages.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the clarification

Comment: There's an answer in this thread that I could modify to produce my desired output, which I'll post for anyone else running into this problem:  https://community.rstudio.com/t/highlighting-text-inline-in-rmarkdown-or-bookdown-pdf/35118/4  Still not sure what's going on with the html/pdf discrepancy

Comment: Good idea, you can answer your own question here!

Comment: It’s more of a hack than an answer to the original question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gainz's suggestion, this finally (!) works for me (thanks Gainz):

````
---
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{soul}
   - \usepackage{color}
output:
     pdf_document:
         latex_engine: xelatex
         extra_dependencies: xcolor
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\hl{you text}
````